# APN Error when uploaded to Server

Tags: c#, ios, apple-push-notifications, x509certificate

I am trying to do apple push notification using c# code. Its working fine on my local machine and I am getting notifications. But when uploaded to server I am getting an exception when tried to create a new certificate. This is the code I am using

```
protected void sendPayLoad(string message, string eqpt_ID)
    {
        try
        {
            if (eqpt_ID == string.Empty || eqpt_ID == " (null)")
            {
                Log_Error_Message("void sendPayLoad(string message, string eqpt_ID)", "No equipment ID");
                return;
            }

            int port;
            String hostname, cert_path, payload;
            string deviceId, certificatePath, certificatePassword;
            X509Certificate2 clientCertificate=null;
            X509Certificate2Collection certificatesCollection=null;
            TcpClient client=null;
            SslStream sslStream=null;
            MemoryStream memoryStream=null;
            BinaryWriter writer=null;
            byte[] b1, array;

            hostname = "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com";// "gateway.push.apple.com";
            cert_path = Session["cert_path"].ToString();
            port = 2195;

            if (cert_path == string.Empty)
            {
                Alert.Show("No certificate found for sending message to customer");
                return;
            }
            //load certificate
            certificatePath = Server.MapPath(cert_path);//Add p12 certificate here
            certificatePassword = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, certificatePassword);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log_Error_Message("void sendPayLoad(string message, string eqpt_ID)", "X509Certificate2 error:- \t " + ex.Message);
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                certificatesCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection(clientCertificate);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log_Error_Message("void sendPayLoad(string message, string eqpt_ID)", "X509Certificate2Collection error:- \t " + ex.Message);
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                client = new TcpClient(hostname, port);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log_Error_Message("void sendPayLoad(string message, string eqpt_ID)", "TcpClient error:- \t " + ex.Message);
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log_Error_Message("void sendPayLoad(string message, string eqpt_ID)", "SslStream or RemoteCertificateValidationCallback error:- \t " + ex.Message);
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, certificatesCollection, SslProtocols.Tls, true);
            }
            catch (AuthenticationException ex)
            {
                client.Close();
                Log_Error_Message("void sendPayLoad(string message, string eqpt_ID)", "AuthenticationException:\n\t" + ex.Message);
                return;
            }

            // Encode a test message into a byte array.
            memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            writer = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);

            writer.Write((byte)0);  //The command
            writer.Write((byte)0);  //The first byte of the deviceId length (big-endian first byte)
            writer.Write((byte)32); //The deviceId length (big-endian second byte)


            deviceId = eqpt_ID;

            writer.Write(HexToData(deviceId.ToUpper()));

            payload = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + message + "\",\"badge\":1}}";

            writer.Write((byte)0); //First byte of payload length; (big-endian first byte)
            writer.Write((byte)payload.Length);     //payload length (big-endian second byte)

            b1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
            writer.Write(b1);
            writer.Flush();

            array = memoryStream.ToArray();
            sslStream.Write(array);
            sslStream.Flush();

            //String deviceId = "DEVICEIDGOESHERE";


            // Close the client connection.
            client.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {           
            Cre_Log_Err_takeaway.Append_Err_Msg("rest/booking.aspx_page", "void sendPayLoad(string message, string eqpt_ID)", ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

While trying to run in server I am getting an excception at this line

```
 try
            {
                clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, certificatePassword);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log_Error_Message("void sendPayLoad(string message, string eqpt_ID)", "X509Certificate2 error:- \t " + ex.Message);
                return;
            }
```

In the logs I am only getting

> An Internal error occured

I have printed out the certificate path and its pointing to this path

> D:\Hosting\8842886\html\testwebsite\certificate_201212725953Pushcerti.p12

Also for this certificate I dont have any password, So I am using **Sting.Empty** I also tried passing an empty string like this **""** .Still no luck.
I have used this code before in live server and it was working fine. This time I am using a godaddy server.

How can I do this properly?

Thanks

Comment: aside from all that code that you posted what error do you get for example if you were to Debug that code on the Server.. also on the server that you are talking about is there a D: drive can you confirm...? can you also compare the difference of the Certificate that's on the working machine vs the one that is not. there has to be something small that's different.. it's probably staring you right in the face in all due respect.. also check the .config file settings or Machine.Config setting just to be sure....

Comment: Checkout this link as well it might help lead you to a quick solution http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/csharplanguage/thread/4011d0ea-3dba-4d04-b6cf-adada7956f02

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this:

Solution 1: set identity of the applicationpool to "LOCALSERVICE" - which I would not prefer(!!)

Solution 2: use the flags `X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable` in the constructor of the X509Certificate2 class.

[MS: x509keystorageflags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509keystorageflags.aspx)